# Create a base class object from a derived class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
public class Base{

    //fields
    public String getStr(){
        String str = null;
        //Getting str from the fields
        return str;
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base{

    //fields
    //some other fileds
    public String getStr(){
        String str = null;
        //Getting str from the fields + some other fields
        return str;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a method which has a parameter of the type `Derived`.

```
public void makeStr(Derived d){
    Base b = null;
    //Getting the Base class subobject from d and printing the str
}
```

But I can't just do assignment like `b = d;` and then invoke `b.getStr()` because the method `d.getStr()` is going to be called.

How can I create the object of the type `Base` from the `Base` subobject of the objec of the type `Derived`? I fact, I just wanta create the copy of the `Base` subobject of the type `Derived`.

Comment: `str` is not a *field*, it's a *method variable*.

Comment: @amit And? We create str from the fields. I think the details of creating that string (like invoking toString() methods on the fields) are not important here.

Comment: I misunderstood your intent, thoguht you were referring to `str` as a field itself

Comment: Is this `Derived` `extends`  `Base` or your code is as it is?

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians Sure, it is. Updated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The whole point of overriding methods in sub-classes is that the method of the sub-class would get executed in run-time, even if the compile time type is that of the super-class.

If for some reason you require an instance of the super-class, you should add a copy constructor to your super-class and use it to create such an instance :

```
public class Base {
    ...
    Base (Base source) {
        // copy the properties from source
    }

}
```

Then :

```
public void makeStr(Derived d)
{ 
    Base b = new Base(d);
    ... b.getStr() will call the Base class implementation
}
```

Comment: Is there a generic way for creating such objects which are the copies of base subobjects? I mean to avoid coping the fields manually.

Comment: @St.Antario you can do it through reflection.

Comment: I meant we already have the base subobject within the derived object. Why do we have to write copying the properties in the constructor explicitly? There's no way to do that without reflection?

Comment: BTW, could you add an example with reflection?

Comment: @St.Antario It could have more fields.

Comment: @St.Antario Why override the method if you want the base implementation to be called? You can prevent overriding of the method if you declare it as final, in which case the base implementation will always get called.

Comment: Somewhere I need the derived implementation. Does it look like a bad design?

Comment: @St.Antario It's hard to say without knowing the actual use case.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in other languages like Python this isn't the case. If you call `self.foo()` for example in a `bar` method and you override `foo` in the subclass - and you call it in the subclass (you don't override bar) it will still call the parent's foo.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a ["Has-a" relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) instead of ["is-a" relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).

In this case, rather than having `Derived` extend `Base`, you can make it have a field of type `Base`.

`Derived` will be a seperate class, with its own functionality, and will support the functionality of `Base`, via its `Base` field.

If it's the correct design or not is really implementation dependent, and it is hard to suggest if it is, based on the information provided.

Comment: Exactly this! In so many cases people should use composition instead of inheritance!!! - Sometimes people just use inheritance because the learned it in school and think to do correct OO you have to have many extends and implements, because it looks fancy.

Answer (score 5):

When you inherit one class from another in Java, there is no such thing as a parent "subobject" for the object of the child class. You seem to be wishing for a prototype-based inheritance, like in JavaScript.

If you wish to access a "subobject", you may want to implement your "inheritance" another way. The Derived object should not inherit from the Base object, but instead wrap it.

```
class Derived {

    private Base base;

    public Derived(Base base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Base getBase() {
        return this.base;
    }
}

public void makeStr(Derived d){
    Base b = d.getBase();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, the "copy subobject" concept OP is talking about seems to be taken directly from C++ - and doesn't make much sense with almost any other language.

Answer (score 5):

Basic idea is that when object of child class created than there is no definition of overridden method of base class object in child class object, so you never get such method of super from child class object.

you can get rest members by just typecasting it.

```
Base castedInBase = derivedObj;
//child class specific member as well as hided fields are also availble here.
```

you can get only object of parent class by using constructor-

```
Base base= new Base(derivedObj);
//orrided method of base class lost,will refer to super class overrided method.
```

let suppose following is your method-

```
public void makeStr(Derived derivedObj){
        Base castedInBase = derivedObj;
    }
```

> NOTE:this is impossible to get overrided method of Parent class from
>   Child class object.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to make the implementation of the base class available, you can do it like:

```
public class Derived extends Base{
    …
    public String getStr(){
        String str = null;
        // produce the specialized string
        return str;
    }
    public String getBaseStr(){
         return super.getStr(); // delegate to base class
    }
}
```

The whole point about it is, that if a class decides to override an inherited method, it also controls for its own instances whether the original method will be made available to other classes.

The `Derived` class can always invoke the original implementation of `Base` for the `this` instance via `super.getStr()`, but in order to invoke it on arbitrary instances (e.g. those passed in as parameter) or to expose this possibility to other classes, you need another method like in the example above. Then you can invoke `getBaseStr()` on arbitrary instances of `Derived`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this.

The derived object instance will forever be attached to its own class. You cannot just "revert" it back to the base class, and you cannot just "skip" its overridden method to go back to the base class' implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assume the `Base` and `Derived` objects share a common feature you could implement an interface

```
public interface IStr {
    String getStr();
}
public class Base implements IStr {
    //...
}
public class Derived implements IStr {
    //...
}
public void makeStr(IStr o) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to copy objects I would go with @Eran answer - create a copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

> I fact, I just wanta create the copy of the Base subobject of the type Derived.

Just do it. Implement copy constructot in your Base

```
public Base(Base b) {
    // assign all required fields from the old object
    ...
}
```

and call it when you want to get Base from Derived:

```
Base b = new Base(d);
```